# Using label with python-gitlab

Tags: gitlab, python-gitlab

According to [Lables](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/labels.html) documentation of python-gitlab, we can use the follwing code to add labels to newly created issues:

```
# Labels are defined as lists in issues and merge requests. The labels must
# exist.
issue = p.issues.create({'title': 'issue title',
                         'description': 'issue description',
                         'labels': ['foo']})
issue.labels.append('bar')
issue.save()
```

Which works fine when "foo" is created on project level.
However it's not working with labels created on parent group level.

Example:
Group1 (labels "boo") > Project1 (labels "foo")

Using the code snipet above, I can apply foo, but not boo.

How can I access parent level labels?
I've tried to use token created on project level, and another one on group level, but still without success.